# Installing GitLab using Raspberry PI 3 with Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, raspberrypi, gitlab

I'm currently trying to install the GitLab CE Version on my Raspberry Pi. I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed on the Raspberry Pi, but I'm unable to install GitLab with `sudo apt install gitlab-ce`:

```
sudo apt install -y curl openssh-server ca-certificates 
sudo apt install -y postfix 
curl -sS https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
sudo EXTERNAL_URL="https://gitlab.example.com" apt install gitlab-ce
```

The error I get is: `Unable to locate package gitlab-ce`

I followed the steps: https://about.gitlab.com/install/#ubuntu?version=ce

I'm a complete beginner in Ubuntu.

Comment: GitLab does NOT provide `gitlab-ce` packages for ARM architectures for Ubuntu.  I went to their repos and searched and they only provide Debian ARM packages.  This suggests that this is why you're getting an "unable to locate package' error, as it doesn't provide Ubuntu packages for the ARM arch.

Comment: @ThomasWard that would mean, that I would have to install a debian os like Raspbian in case to install gitlab?

Comment: *Technially* yes, but keep in mind this also, GitLab recommends AT MINIMUM 4GB of RAM.  1GB from an RPi will be EXTREMELY slow and probably isn't going to be enough to run GitLab.  Most git frontends like GitLab aren't built for ARM, they're built for x86 (not ARM, so i386 and amd64 primarily).  But once you switch off Ubuntu that's offtopic for here.

Comment: -- Update 11-18 -- After using it for a couple of hours, it works well but the CPU is pegged at 60+ percent with high memory usage. Consider yourselves warned. -- Origional -- As a year has passed, things have gotten updated. I just installed gitlab-ce on a Raspberry Pi 4 4GB running Ubuntu Server 20.04. Follow the instructions here. https://about.gitlab.com/install/#ubuntu